# I am getting error in the following Query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT category 
FROM
    (SELECT  Category
     FROM Table
     ORDER BY 
         CASE
             WHEN Category = 'A' THEN 1
             WHEN Category = 'C' THEN 2
             WHEN Category = 'D' THEN 3
             WHEN Category = 'e' THEN 4) a
ORDER BY 
    Category
```

Comment: In your case expression `end` is missing.

Comment: @YogeshSharma If so, then vote to close as a typo question.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply this without subquery :

```
SELECT Category
FROM Table t 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Category = 'A' THEN 1
               WHEN Category = 'C' THEN 2
               WHEN Category = 'D' THEN 3
               WHEN Category = 'e' THEN 4 
               ELSE 5 
           END);
```